# How to format a Dataframe converted from a dictionary

Tags: python, linux, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I am very new to python + coding in general and am having an issue with dataframes in pandas.

I am reading through a file of Amazon reviews (files can be found here:http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Amazon-links.html) and wish to create a dataframe from the data.

I have been able to convert the reviews into a dict, and set it to the dataframe, but the output is giving me 3 seperate dataframes for every column value.

How to join the three dataframes into one with the column_names=["Names",Prices","Number of Scores","Mean Scores"] and rows =[dict_key:[prices, num scores, mean score]

I think the issue is either white spaces or \n.  However,I am having an issue figuring out where to split the white spaces. I thought I had already split the reviews my line in the beginning of my code.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am just very lost right now. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics 
#!pip install pandas==0.23.4

data = open('Pet_Supplies.txt','r')
data_text = data.read()
data_split = data_text.strip().split('\n\n')
data.close()
review_dict={}
for x in data_split:  
  names_obj=re.search('(product/title:\s)(.*)',x)
  names=names_obj.group(2)
  prices_obj = re.search('product/price:\s(.*)\n',x) 
  prices = prices_obj.group(1)
  score_obj = re.search('\d\.\d\n',x)
  scores=score_obj.group(0)
  if names in review_dict:
    num_reviews = review_dict[names][1]+1
    sum_scores = float(scores)*float(num_reviews)
    mean_score = sum_scores/num_reviews
    review_dict[names]=[prices,num_reviews,mean_score]
  else:
       review_dict[names]=[prices,1,float(scores)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(review_dict, orient='index',columns=("Price","Number of Reviews","Mean Price")).rename_axis('Names')
print(df)
``

I expected the results to be:


Name             Price    Num Reviews  Mean Score

Product_1         8.0              14            4.3


My actual code gives me:

                                                     Price  \
Names                                                         
Orbee Tuff Ball Orange - SMALL                         6.95  

                                                     Number of Reviews  \
Names                                                                   
Orbee Tuff Ball Orange - SMALL                         4 

                                                     Mean Price  
Names                                                           
Orbee Tuff Ball Orange - SMALL                         5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear what you are wanting to do is alter the display options to view the dataframe, not change the dataframe itself which looks just fine to me.

If you'd like to see each row of the dataframe on a single line when you print it to the screen you could change the pandas display options. For example using `pd.set_option('display.width', 180)` will make the dataframe run the whole way across a standard size monitor (the default width is 90, half of the screen so that two outputs can be viewed side by side).

Perhaps you do actually want to change the dataframe. The reason you are seeing the "Names" information repeated is because it is the index of your dataframe. If you removed the "Names" from the index of the dataframe and make that a column it will print differently. You can do that with `df = df.reset_index()`. Now the index will just be a series of numbers and "Names" will be a column in the data. Try it and see how the dataframe prints after that. Keep playing around, but ultimately these are just personal preferences based on what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go with the pd.set_option('display.width', 180) option and it worked wonderfully!

Comment: Hey @JoannaVandyke if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!